# 2-d interpolation ignoring nan values

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, interpolation

How do you tell interp2d to ignore nan values?

I have a surface x and y with some arbitrary value z.

```
x =   np.array([[9.19632, 9.62141, 10.0829, np.isnan, np.isnan],
        [9.21164, 9.64347, 10.1392, 10.5698,  np.isnan],
        [9.22175, 9.65439, 10.1423, 10.6301, 11.0323],
        [9.21632, 9.67060, 10.1474, 10.6230, 11.0818]])

y =  np.array([[11.5466,11.6485,11.7619, np.isnan, np.isnan],
        [12.4771, 12.5460, 12.5453, 12.7142, np.isnan],
        [13.5578, 13.5581, 13.5505, 13.5309, 13.6081],
        [14.5653, 14.5504, 14.5036, 14.5145, 14.5060]])

z = np.array([[0.466113, 0.0484404, -0.385355, np.isnan, np.isnan],
        [0.366125, -0.160165, -0.548668, -0.888301,np.isnan],
        [-0.0970777, -0.346734, -0.826576, -1.08412, -1.33129],
        [-0.259981, -0.586938, -1.03477, -1.32384, -1.61500]])
```

[image]

I have been able to produce the above colour mesh using a masked array but I'm failing when I try an create a finer grid using 2d interpolation. Below is what I have so far, note that I set the nan values to zero to obtain this so obviously it messes up the 'correct' interpolation. Instead I would like to ignore them and leave the parameter space blank.

```
f = interp.interp2d(x,y,z, kind='linear')
xnew = np.arange(9,11.5, 0.01)
ynew = np.arange(9,15, 0.01)
znew = f(xnew, ynew)


levels = np.linspace(zmin, zmax, 15)
plt.ylabel('Y', size=15)
plt.xlabel('X', size=15)
cmap = plt.cm.jet_r
cmap.set_bad('white',0.1) # set nan to white
cs = plt.contourf(xnew, ynew, znew, levels=levels, cmap=cmap)
cbar = plt.colorbar(cs)
cbar.set_label('Z', rotation=90, fontsize=15) # gas fraction
plt.show()
```

[image: contour with nan set to zero]

I want to simply create a smooth colour plot where the regions bound by x and y are coloured according to z.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know why interp2d has problems with irregular spaced data, I would recommend using griddata, you can flat your input data into a vector with `ravel` and then eliminate the NaN, and use it as input of griddata, you would get something like this

[image]

Code is not much different from what you have

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

x =   np.array([[9.19632, 9.62141, 10.0829,np.isnan,np.isnan],
    [9.21164, 9.64347, 10.1392, 10.5698,np.isnan],
    [9.22175, 9.65439, 10.1423, 10.6301, 11.0323],
    [9.21632, 9.67060, 10.1474, 10.6230, 11.0818]])

y =  np.array([[11.5466,11.6485,11.7619,np.isnan,np.isnan],
    [12.4771, 12.5460, 12.5453, 12.7142,np.isnan],
    [13.5578, 13.5581, 13.5505, 13.5309, 13.6081],
    [14.5653, 14.5504, 14.5036, 14.5145, 14.5060]])

z = np.array([[0.466113, 0.0484404, -0.385355,np.isnan,np.isnan],
    [0.366125, -0.160165, -0.548668, -0.888301,np.isnan],
    [-0.0970777, -0.346734, -0.826576, -1.08412, -1.33129],
    [-0.259981, -0.586938, -1.03477, -1.32384, -1.61500]])

x=x.ravel()              #Flat input into 1d vector
x=list(x[x!=np.isnan])   #eliminate any NaN
y=y.ravel()
y=list(y[y!=np.isnan])
z=z.ravel()
z=list(z[z!=np.isnan])


xnew = np.arange(9,11.5, 0.01)
ynew = np.arange(9,15, 0.01)
znew = griddata((x, y), z, (xnew[None,:], ynew[:,None]), method='linear')



levels = np.linspace(min(z), max(z), 15)
plt.ylabel('Y', size=15)
plt.xlabel('X', size=15)
cmap = plt.cm.jet_r
cs = plt.contourf(xnew, ynew, znew, levels=levels, cmap=cmap)
cbar = plt.colorbar(cs)
cbar.set_label('Z', rotation=90, fontsize=15) # gas fraction
plt.show()
```

---

If you must extrapolate data (check my comment below) you can use `SmoothBivariateSpline` and play around with the order of the spline, I don't recommend it, I'll show you why.

The code is closer to what you had originally.

```
from scipy.interpolate import SmoothBivariateSpline

x=x.ravel()
x=(x[x!=np.isnan])
y=y.ravel()
y=(y[y!=np.isnan])
z=z.ravel()
z=(z[z!=np.isnan])

xnew = np.arange(9,11.5, 0.01)
ynew = np.arange(10.5,15, 0.01)

f = SmoothBivariateSpline(x,y,z,kx=1,ky=1)

znew=np.transpose(f(xnew, ynew))
```

With kx=1 and ky=1 `f = SmoothBivariateSpline(x,y,z,kx=1,ky=1)` you get

[image]

With kx=2 and ky=2 you get:

[image]

And with kx=3 and ky=3 you get:

[image]

I changed the levels on the 3 pictures so it's easier to see. But check the scale, the values can get crazy very fast outside your sampling area, so if you MUST extrapolate, do it with diligence

Comment: Thanks - works much better than interp2d. Is it possible to extrapolate z values for the xnew,ynew coordinates that are outside the input grid?
You can set them to constant using 'fill_value' keyword or create a rather ugly aproximation using the 'nearest' method. However, I would ideally like a smooth extrapolation at each xnew,ynew so the parameter space is filled.

Comment: Extrapolation in 2d is kinda-non-trivial issue, depending in what you are doing it may be better to have the NaN so you know that it is outside the samplig area, but if you must, maybe a linear extrapolation is a safe bet, but you can get out of bounds really quickly. I'll edit the answer to include some images  of extrapolating with `SmoothBivariateSpline`

Comment: I agree, you have to be wary of 2d extrapolation and this is a good example of why. Could you edit to show how you put in the `SmoothBivariateSpline` class please. Thanks for help.

Comment: Sure, i'ts a different import, I'll add it, the code is even closer to what you had originally

Comment: Ah transpose(!). It makes sense now :)

Comment: Oh yeah, that, I don't know why it gives the array rotated, I had to transpose it. Mark it as one of those quirks that just happen

Comment: Why are you removing the `nan` from the lists? I think `griddata` can handle those.

Comment: @FooBar `griddata` can handle `nan` as values of the function to interpolate, but not as coordinates. And since the original question had `nan` also as coordinates, it was easier to remove them all together